# Brackets operator overload on std::array<std::array<T, N2>, N> data member

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, operator-overloading

So, consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<class T, std::size_t N, std::size_t N2>
struct foo
{
    std::array<std::array<T, N2>, N> data;

    T& operator[](std::size_t index) { return data[index]; }
};

int main()
{
    foo<int, 3, 3> obj;
    std::cout << obj[2][2]; //boom
}
```

This is my logic:
`obj[2]` by itself returns a `std::array<T, N2>` object, so applying `operator[]` again to that (`obj[2][2]`), should give me the result I need. So actually with `obj[2]` it's calling `foo`'s `operator[]`, while with `obj[2][2]` it's calling `std::array<T, N>`'s `operator[]`. Obviously not.

**Question**: What is going on in the example above and why is my logic faulty?

Comment: Your `operator[]` is declared to return a `T&` but then it attempts to return a `std::array<T, N2>&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of the `operator[]` is not right. The expression `data[index]` is of the type `std::array<T, N2>` and You tell the compiler you return a `T&`, which is false. Your function should look like this:

```
std::array<T, N2>& operator[](std::size_t index) { return data[index]; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at your `operator[]`. It returns `T&`, which in your case is `int&`. `data[index]`, on the other hand, is of type `std::array<T, N2>&`, which in this case is `std::array<int, 3>&`.

Changing the operator's return type should fix this:

```
    std::array<T, N2>& operator[](std::size_t index) { return data[index]; }
```